# Can anyone translate? Etching on the sword

Tags: translation

[image]

I bought this sword online.  No idea what it says.

Comment: Translation requests are not on topic here at chinese.se, sorry. P.S. you're holding it upside down: 今古有神奉志士 and that makes this a replica sword from the movie The Last Samurai, making it Japanese, and not Chinese. According to the movie, it says "I belong to the warrior in whom the old ways have joined the new." - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0325710/quotes?item=qt0456450

Comment: can we establish a subreddit for these kinds of requests? And or get the site to automatically flash a suggestion to redirect the request elsewhere when it detects words like "translate" or "translation" coming from people with below X reputation.

Comment: Interesting idea @MasterSparkles!

Comment: And the translation given by the movie seems fairly far from what the characters say.  OP should find someone who knows Japanese to discuss it with him.